# UIScrollView has its own dot indictators?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a ViewController with a view that contains a ScrollView and a PageControl positioned at the bottom.

What I noticed however, is that the ScrollView already has its own set of 3 dot indicators.  So, just for the sake of testing, if I move around my PageControl bar, I can actually see two sets of dot indicators.

I have my IBOutlet set to my PageControl, so the dots get updated as I'd expect.  However, the dots on the ScrollView don't change (and there are always 3 of them).

Why does the ScrollView already have its own dots?  I tried unchecking "Show horizontal scrollers" but this did not get rid of the dots.

I guess why question is two-fold:  How could I remove the dots from the ScrollView since I really only want the PageControl?  Secondly, what is the purpose of having those dots on the ScrollView itself?

To be clear, I've already unchecked the Show horizontal and vertical scrollers in Interface Builder.  I have also disabled them programatically:

```
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know where the dots are coming from. I assume you added another UIPageControl by accident. The properties "showsHorizontalScrollIndicator" and "showsVerticalScrollIndicator" however are used to show or hide the scrollbars and have nothing to do with the paging indicators.

Comment: UIScrollView doesn't create page controls. You need to check if yo do not have double instance od page control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIScrollView does not have dots. Maybe you added two UIPageControls accidentally. If you show more code maybe we can help but all I can tell you is that a UIScrollView is not the source of the dots.

Comment: Or if you're using someone else's code e.g.; code samples or open source code.